# Is "half-a-dozen" an accepted term?

Tags: etymology, slang

I suspect that the parent term is "half of a dozen" which is just being shortened to half-a-dozen. But I caught myself using half-dozen earlier today and wondered which of the variants are considered valid. Both half-dozen and half-a-dozen seem odd written out even though they sound fine to my ear.

Comment: Six of one, half a dozen of the other.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found this in *Garner's Modern American Usage*'s entry on *half*.

> **half.
>
>    A. *Half* (*of*).** The preposition *of* is often unnecessary. Omit it when you can. [...]
>   **C. *a half dozen* and *half a dozen.*** For this noun phrase, either *a half dozen* or *half a dozen* is good form. Avoid *a half a dozen*. When the phrase is used as an adjective, it becomes a phrasal adjective that should be hyphenated: *a half-dozen twirlers with the band*.

Comment: +1; This prompted me to actually check my dictionary where I found the same: _Half-dozen_ and _half a dozen_. TIL.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that "one half dozen", "a half dozen", and "half dozen" are all *accepted*, however someone who is more knowledgeable than I will have to attest to whether any of those is actually accurate from a grammatical perspective.

This Ngram chart has some interesting findings, however. There are virtually no occurrences of the phrase "half of a dozen" in the English literature over the last 400 years, while the phrase "half a dozen" seemed to peak in the early 1900s, decline over the next century, and then pick up again of late. Meanwhile, the term "half dozen" has seen a similar rise and fall as "half a dozen," but with markedly less variance.

[image]

Comment: And there's a [similar Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=half%20a%20hundred%2Chalf%20hundred%2Chalf%20of%20a%20hundred&corpus=0&smoothing=3&year_start=1700&year_end=2000) for half hundred and half a hundred, where "half of a hundred" is virtually never used.

Comment: @Peter Shor - Usually when I hear "half a hundred", it is in reference to (American) College Football. If one team bludgeons its opponent so badly that they score more than 50 points (at 7ish a touchdown, that would work out to 6 or more TD's), they are said to have "hung have a hundred" on them. I believe OU's Barry Switzer originated this term.

Answer (score 1):

The OED actually has a full entry for this phrase:

> The half of a dozen; six (or about
>   six). Const.: see dozen.
>
> a.    **1829** T. L. Peacock Misfort. of
>   Elphin vi, Some half-dozen‥forgers.
>      **1855** Thackeray Newcomes I. 7
>   Pointing out a half dozen of people in
>   the room.    **1865** Derby Mercury 15
>   Feb., I‥might have laid hold of some
>   half-dozen at least.    Mod. Would you
>   like another half-dozen?
>
> b.    **c 1401** Jack Upland in Pol. Poems
>   (Rolls) II. 69 The cloith of oo man
>   Myȝte hele half a doseyne.
>      **1420–1555** [see dozen n. 1].    **1648**
>   Gage West Ind. 12 He offered unto me
>   halfe a dozen of Spanish pistols.
>      Ibid. 80 Halfe a dozen Hollanders
>   leapt into the boat after him.    **1711**
>   Addison Spect. No. 1. ⁋5 Half a dozen
>   of my select Friends.    **1843** Borrow
>   Bible in Spain 145 We came suddenly
>   upon half-a-dozen fellows, armed with
>   muskets.

So the phrase "half a dozen" has been standard for more than 6 centuries.  Use it at will!

Answer (score 0):

In the Editor’s Note to the 1987 edition of the Peterson Field Guides, “Hawks,” Roger Tory Peterson writes, “When I was a young man, 50 years ago, my friends and I knew of scarcely more than half of dozen good spots where...”.

Comment: While this shows an example of the terminology in use, how does it actually answer the question if it is valid?